# Chamando arquivo a cada execução do TimThumb

Tags: php, imagem

Uso o [TimThumb](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) para upload de imagens e redimensionamento das mesmas. Porém, ao fim do projeto, fazendo modificações no `.htaccess` para otimização (ativando gzip, minify, leverage browser caching e mais), persistiu algo que eu considero erro:

O TimThumb está sendo executado uma vez, em cada imagem, note na figura abaixo:
[image: note o carregamento de diversos tim.php]

Teria algum método para eu fazer um Loop no script? Cada `tim.php` relatado na imagem acima é uma imagem carregada por ele, as URLs estão sendo mostradas da seguinte forma:

```
http://meusite.com.br/tim.php?src=http://meusite.com.br/uploads/2013/11/nomedaimg&w=160&h=80&zc=1&q=100&a=t
```

Meu site está demorando 5 segundos para abrir, isso tá incomodando muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após conhecer um pouco sobre essa biblioteca de imagens e analisar o gráfico da pergunta, posso comentar sobre algumas possíveis causas da lentidão...

#### O TimThumb está processando sempre todas as imagens

Esse não parece ser o caso, já que várias linhas do gráficas mostram apenas barras verdes, o que significa que o tempo foi gasto com transferência de imagens e não processamento.

Note que não faz muita diferença a URL ser `tim.php`, desde que a biblioteca estiver apenas escrevendo uma imagem em *cache* para a saída, pois isso é rápido.

De qualquer forma, verifique se as imagens estão sendo gravadas no diretório configurado para cache. Se não estiverem, ajuste a permissão do script para a pasta.

#### O TimThumb está enviando algum *header* que impede o cache

Utilize a ferramenta do desenvolvedor do seu *browser* (<kbd>F12</kbd>?) para monitorar a rede e verificar se, após acessar a mesma página pela segunda vez, as imagens serão carregadas do cache do navegador e não feito o *download* novamente.

#### Seu servidor é lento

Sinceramente, para algumas hospedagens compartilhadas, 5 segundos é até um tempo razoável para o nível de processamento que seu site parece estar usando. Eu mesmo uso a bluehost para meu blog e, se não fosse os plugins de cache do Wordpress, o tempo de carregamento poderia facilmente chegar ao dobro disso.

#### Grande número de arquivos baixados

Outra fator visto no gráfico é que há um grande número de elementos baixados no acesso à página. Isso também causa um impacto negativo, mesmo que sua banda de rede seja boa, pois os navegadores limitam o número de conexões simultâneas. O limite geralmente fica entre 2 e 6 conexões ([veja esta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)).

Entretanto, isso seria bem amenizado no seu caso após o segundo acesso ao site, pois pelos menos as *web fonts*, estilos e scripts seriam colocados em cache no navegador. Lógico que o preço seria pago no primeiro acesso, mas se o conteúdo for bom vale a pena.

#### Conclusão

Estou propenso a pensar que não há um problema específico com o TimThumb.

Eu faria alguns testes colocando imagens estáticas e também verificando se o navegador consegue usar o cache adequadamente e carregar a página mais rapidamente a partir do segundo acesso.

Finalmente, se a questão fosse desempenho, há técnicas para melhorar isso, como contratar um servidor mais potente ou mesmo um serviços mais especializado de cache na nuvem.

Answer (score 0):

### Ajax para evitar a espera do usuário

Bom dia, você já considerou passar um array com o src das imagens para uma função que fizesse o loop do timthumb, pegando o resultado por ajax? Acredito que isso seria interessante.

### Redimensionamento uma única vez.

Outra coisa. O wordpress por exemplo gera todas as miniaturas uma única vez, várias dimensões padrão, não sendo necessário refazê-las a cada *refresh* da página. Dessa forma, seguir essa idéia é bem válida.

Você geraria vários tamanhos (se for necessário) ou o tamanho que você deseja.

> 1. **Thumbnail** (padrão 150px x 150px)
> 2. **Tamanho médio** (padrão 300px x 300px)
> 3. **Tamanho grande** (padrão 640px x 640px)
> 4. **Tamanho original** (sem modificação)

Depois disso, você poderia verificar a existência da pasta especifica das miniaturas para cada imagem, isso se você não quiser manter o histórico em uma tabela no BD.

Comment: O luiz apenas editou a pergunta... rsrs

Comment: kkkk desculpe. Ainda estou com sono. :/